# Objective-C display array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nslog, viewdidload

I have created a `NSMutableArray` called `myArray` where I insert, using SQL statement, three variables.
The one variable is a string and the other two double.
Then in the `viewDidLoad` I want to display the array.

Specificly I have used:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {  
    NSLog(@"%@",myArray);  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
}
```

But it displays `"<0x16145a70>"' "<0x16145ab0>"` and so on...

I think the problem is that `myArray` contains two types of format (string and double).

What does the code need to display readable data of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different types of data, you should print these out yourself

This will give you output similar to what you're after:

```
for(id element in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [element description]);
}
```

Comment: You mean something like                                      
     for(NSString *name in myArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",name);
    }

Comment: From what you said, your array contains 'a string and the other two double'. I assumed this meant one NSString, and two NSNumbers. In this case, the description message is part of the NSObject, which (obviously) both NSString and NSNumber derive from. Using what you say will work, because it will actually just call the description message. At which point, any object in your array, whether it is actually an NSString or not, will respond to description. If you don't want to use `id, at least use NSObject to avoid any accidents later on if things change.

Comment: Now I have used ViewController *data=[myArrayobjectAtIndex:0];NSString *aname=data.Name;NSLog(@"%@",aname); and it displays the correct value

Answer (score 0):

That is interesting output.  NSObject-description usually provides more information than just the physical address of the object.  You may have an issue where myArray is no longer a valid NSArray when your code reaches the NSLog.  It is also important that the doubles be wrapped into an NSNumber for insertion into the array.